# How can I wrap the items inside details in a container using JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I can't change the markup because it's generated by my CMS.

Therefore, I need my current markup:

```
<details class="js-form-wrapper>
  <summary></summary>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <table class="responsive"></table>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file"></div>
</details>
```

To become like this using JQuery:

```
<details class="js-form-wrapper>
    <summary></summary>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  <div class="my-wrapper">
    <table class="responsive"></table>
    <div class="js-form-type-managed-file"></div>
  </div>
</details>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing `"` on `<details class="js-form-wrapper>`

Comment: You forgot to post the jQuery code you're having issues with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.wrapAll()](https://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) and call multiple elements since they are not under one parent tag

```html
<details class="js-form-wrapper">
  <summary>summ</summary>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <table class="responsive"></table>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file">child</div>
</details>
```

```js
  $(".js-form-wrapper table, .js-form-type-managed-file").wrapAll('<div class="my-wrapper"></div>');
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-form-wrapper table, .js-form-type-managed-file").wrapAll('<div class="my-wrapper"></div>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="js-form-wrapper">
  <summary>summary</summary>
  <div>div 1</div>
  <div>div 2</div>
  <table class="responsive"></table>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file">inspect here to see wrap</div>
</details>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a few ways to do this but a simple one would be:

```
$('table').next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="my-wrapper">');
```

```js
$('details table').next().addBack().wrapAll('<div class="my-wrapper">');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<details class="js-form-wrapper">
  <summary></summary>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <table class="responsive"></table>
  <div class="js-form-type-managed-file "></div>
</details>
```